# Нужно дастать ключ по значению в JSON

Tags: javascript, json

let x = {"r1":44.4, "r2":null, "r3":38.8, "r4":45.66, "r5":40.19};
Надо достать ключь со значением null используя JSON

Comment: Вы даете кому-то задание? Где ваша попытка решения?

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
for ([key, val] of Object.entries(x)) {
    if (val === null) {
        console.log(key);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: А можно for of расписать как for(i=.... i<= ....length i++) ? чтоб я понял что к чему

Comment: нельзя.... т.к. это не массив и тут применяется другое правило итерирования

Comment: Чтобы понимать что тут к чему - изучите метод **[Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)** и **[Деструктурирующее присваивание](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)**